# inequality of $(ax+by+cz)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, inequality

The Cauchy Schwarz inequality says
$$
(ax+by+cz)^2 = (a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2).
$$

I found that there is a kind of analogous inequality for $(ax+by+cz)^n$
$$
(x+y+z)^n \leq 3^n(x^n+y^n +z^n).
$$
if I remember it correctly.

How to prove this inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factor can be improved to $3^{n-1}$. For odd $n$ you have to assume probably that $x,y,z \geq 0$. Then this is [Jensen’s inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) for the monomial function $x \mapsto x^n$: $$\left(\frac{x+y+z}3\right)^n \leq \frac{x^n + y^n + z^n}3.$$

Comment: the formula is true for $n\in [0,1]$ and nonnegative variables as well with constant 1

Answer (score 0):

We have, for $x, y, z \ge 0$,
$$(x + y + z)^n \le 3^n \max\{x, y, z\}^n \le 3^n(x^n + y^n + z^n).$$